# Installer fails no matter what I try

Tags: system-installation

I’m fairly new to Linux systems so please forgive me if I make any mistakes. I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a Alienware desktop. Whenever I run the launcher it ends up failing. I have tried everything from using   usb sticks and ssds to manually deleting every partition on the drive I want to install to before running the installer. From what I can figure out, it fails with this error:

```
 Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['unshare’, ‘--fork’, ‘--pid’, ‘—‘, ‘chroot’, ‘/target’, ‘efibootmgr’, ‘o’, ‘1003,0000,0001,0002’]
Exit code: 8
Reason: -
Stdout: ‘ ‘
Stderr: ‘
```

I should also note that I turned secureboot off and updated to the latest version of the bios.
If there is any more information that I can provide please let me know. Thanks!
Edit to add information requested:

- The desktop is an Alienware Aura R10 (Early 2020) with a Ryzen chipset
- The installer fails when it gets to the pannel that shows it installing things, specifically when it gets to `configuring target system bootloader` and `installing grub to target devices`
  -It is set to UEFI
- I am giving the installer a full disk to work with (not specifying partition)
- I am using 18.04 LTS because 20.04 is completely broken graphically no matter what I try (probably because of my navidia GPU) and because what I am planning to install on it only officially supports that version.

Comment: Which step in the installer fails with that error? And how old is your laptop? Is it set to UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: A number of questions spring to mind: (1) which model of desktop and what specs does the device have? (2) why 18.04 rather than a newer release? (3) are you manually specifying partitions or letting the installer do its own thing? (4) did you [validate the Ubuntu Server ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) before writing it to a USB stick? I've deployed thousands of Ubuntu servers over the last 15+ years and not run into this particular issue, so any details you can offer will make it more likely that someone can offer an answer 

Comment: To answer some questions  - The desktop is an Alienware Aura R10 (Early 2020) with a Ryzen chipset (3900X). The MOBO is a custom-made by dell, not sure how to get the specs of it.
- The installer fails when it gets to the panel that shows it installing things, specifically when it gets to `configuring target system bootloader` and `installing grub to target devices`
-It is set to UEFI
-I haven't tried the validator, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I'm confused about the problems you are having "graphically" while attempting to install Ubuntu Server. Ubuntu Server doesn't have a desktop environment or graphical user interface. What problems are you having exactly? Also, I would not call a desktop "old" that is from 2020, especially when you are trying to install a version of an OS that is twice as old  Your best bet is 20.04 since your hardware is newer than the 18.04 release

Comment: Ok I’ll give it another try tomorrow, the issue I’m having is that after I get past the initial screen (I don’t know what it is called but the one where you hit the Ubuntu installer button), the computer reboots and all that is shown is thin pink and green lines, eventually the orange of the installer window can be seen, I’ve tried adding nomodset to the kernel line to no avail.